# How to trace into a third party dll with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reverse-engineering

My application is using a third party dll and works fine,

but I'm seriously interested how things are implemented,

is there anyhow I can trace into the internals of that dll without source code?

Yes,I want to do it right in vs,I'm not familiar with IDA etc at all..

Comment: Are you ok with raw assembler? Or do you want it decompiled into C/C++/C#/VB/Whatever? Does the DLL include debug symbols?

Comment: I just want to see how it works internally.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy: just open disassembly window, and hit "step in" button.